# How does jQuery DataTables filtering work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I've got an example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/52QTk/).  On the keypress event in the search box for the DataTable I print to the console the number of rows in the `tbody` element on the table.  In my example the data is coming from an HTML table.  I'd like to know how is the filtering being done?  Is DataTables re-drawing the table every time on a filtering event?